# Did someone break the font?

Tags: bug, status-completed, achievements-dialog

I just refreshed a couple of different SE sites & the Achievements drop menu seems to have gone all-bold.

I'm hoping that's not intentional.

Before...

[image: Achievements drop down with regular text]

After... [different Stack as I can't go back to the previous version]

[image: Achievements drop down with bolded text on questions' titles]

Inbox affected too, but only for Unread items...

[image: inbox too]

*After comments* - this appears to be a new accessibility feature [though currently buggy].
Could it be opt-in rather than compulsory, for those of use who don't need it?

Comment: I encountered the same phenomenon on two separate SE sites.  Like you, if this was intentional, it was a bad call.

Comment: Inbox too, but only for new entries.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - yes, I just spotted that too as replies are coming in about this.

Comment: I was assembling a bug report when yours popped up.  The blue highlighting is also darker for me (for new entries).

Comment: We had an accessibility request to make new items more distinct from viewed ones, so the changes to the background color and bold text are intentional there. The stuff that's already been viewed should not be in bold. We're working on seeing what went wrong. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @Catija - Thank you for coming to the rescue... but the trouble with 'accessibility' is it should be 'opt in if you need it' [bug or no bug] It shouldn't be 'for everyone whether you want it or not'.

Comment: I appreciate the efforts to make the new items more visible!  Looks like you've got some BoldOverflow there, though. :-)  In case it helps, I noticed a difference between achievements and inbox: for achievements everything is always bold, while for inbox, when there's a new entry only *that* one is bold and the older ones aren't.

Comment: @MonicaCellio We don't need so much BO on SE, I agree!

Comment: @Tetsujin the change stands out because it's new (and also because of the bug), but I don't think it's going to get in your way long-term, and it helps people who face a lot of barriers to using Internet resources we take for granted.  Everything that gets put behind an option adds complexity, so it's not free.  Bold as a marker for "new" is not uncommon in my experience.  I think we'll get used to it.

Comment: @Tetsujin - accessibility stuff should ideally be opt-out, not opt-in

Comment: I agree, @Mithrandir.  Let me know how I can opt-out?  If that isn't an option yet, then it should be.  Whichever: opt-in or opt-out, preferably the latter, is not currently an option, and it ought to be.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Your last comment: this is probably true.  I'd just like to know how "new achievements" are defined, so not necessarily all of the list is bold-faced.  Must one necessarily click on each and every drop-down bold-faced link to make it become "old", or is it sufficient to have clicked on "reputation" on one's profile, to, say, "make old" incoming rep alerts?

Comment: @JedrekMansfield "new" means "unread". Opening the menu is all that it takes to clear it.

Comment: I understand that.  That makes perfect sense for incoming *comments*.  I am asking, since it was suggested that only new notifications of comments AND of **new** achievements, are bold-faced.  But I can read (am notified also of) "new achievements" on each activity tab of my profiles for the sites I am using.  Reading those notifications ought to be linked to "has been read" on the drop down for achievements.  Else, am I to understand that only new *comments/notifications* are in bold-face until read, but ALL items under the "achievements" tab will always remain bold-faced, @Catija ?

Comment: @JedrekMansfield I'm confused. This should only impact the inbox and achievements drop downs. **Anything** that appears in the drop down will be bold the first time you click the icon in the top bar to view them. After viewing the list once, subsequent clicks on the icon will remove the bold face. The achievements being bold constantly *is the bug*, as I said in my first comment. They should only be bold when they're unread.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for clarifying the matter in the your last comment.  I wasn't sure from previous comments that "always bold" achievements was considered a *bug* or not by you or others.  I'm totally on board with your last sentence in your last comment.

Comment: @JedrekMansfield Great. :D I think there's a fix that'll be put out shortly.

Comment: @Catija - The trouble with 'accessibility' features is they can often make things *harder* to read, not easier. I find that bold text much less clear than the regular, so as someone who's a bit short-sighted as opposed to 'in need of accessibility' my experience is worsened by this new 'helpful' feature.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just fixed this.

I'd accidentally left emboldened font in a rule for all of these elements in our less file instead of just for the ones with the unread-item label. It was something I'd put in during testing to figure out where the put the rule on the unread-items label but I forgot to take it out after.

Sorry! Thank you all for finding it quickly so I could take it back out!

Comment: Thanks for following up!!

Comment: ︎ Welcome to Stack Exchange. We all make mistakes — thanks for fixing it so promptly!

Comment: Is that supposed to embolden badge notifications as well? If so, well, [it doesn't seem to be working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t21LB.png). Sorry for the dark image, took the screenshot with my luminosity filter on and forgot it gets captured as well

Comment: If needed, as it raised confusion with Catija: the above screenshot is taken from the review page on mobile. See chat transcript starting [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50994971#50994971)